How can I change directories from the Gnome text editor?
I am a new Linux user. I have installed Ubuntu 24.04, which installed with the Gnome front end.
I can open the default text editor but cannot change directories. I would like to see the entire file system, change directories from there, and run programs.

It is difficult to understand what you mean. What are you exactly trying to do to change directories and see the file system? This is a very basic functionality of Ubuntu and should work just fine.

Text editor is for editing text, not for running programs. In Linux you didn't have access right to some of the system folders. Edit your question and add details of exactly what you are trying to do. Add a screenshot of possible.

Install Midnight Commander.

In Text Editor use the hamburger menu ≡ and select Save As... navigating to the folder you wish to save the file to or use the Create Folder icon.
